# Template Value Error [gidNumber] phpLDAPadmin

Tags: openldap

I'm try using phpLDAPadmin to connect openldap server, but when I try to create new user account with Generic: User Account, I get the error :

"Template Value Error
This template uses a selection list for attribute [gidNumber], however the selection list is empty.
You may need to create some dependancy entries in your LDAP server so that this attribute renders with values. Alternatively, you may be able to define the appropriate selection values in the template file."

I'm quite newbie with ldap and I had tried to search error related with gidNumber but don't have result, I don't know how to solve it. However, I can using software LdapAdmin to connect server and add new uid acc, and I using Ubuntu Server 13.04 to install ldap server. Hope someone can help me out with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You probably just want to create an end user account by selecting the 'Default' option and selecting the inetOrgPerson object class and click the "Proceed" button. On the next screen, you can complete the attribute template to create your entry.

If you really do want a Posix account, first create a Generic: Posix group. After the group is created, the Group ID field will be populated in the Generic User template.

Answer (score 5):

try to make o (organization), ou (organization unit), g (group) then try to make some user.. GID is Group ID, so when GID is empty the template value is error :)